# why use static method when it can be non-static?

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods

I'm new to C#, just a question on the design idea of using static method. For example, we know that Char is struct and has the following static method:

```
public static bool IsDigit(Char c);
```

so when we check if a char is a digit, we can code :

```
char myChar = '8';
if (char.IsDigit(myChar)) {
   ...
}
```

but why language implementers make this specific design decision? they can also make it non-static as:

```
public bool IsDigit();
```

so we can code like:

```
char myChar = '8';
if (myChar.IsDigit()) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: There are overloads to [`Char.IsDigit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.8) that don't take a `char`. It's hard to see how these would work. Maybe one instance method, and another `static`? As far as I can see nothing about your premises is incorrect, but IIRC "why did language implementers make this specific design decision?"-type questions tend to be OT here.

Comment: For these kinds of questions, I'd recommend looking at the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.8 That would have shown the scenario that @spender is referring to.

Comment: To save memory.  You could have 100 instances of the class and static properties are in global space and the is only one occurrence of property instead of 100 instances.

Comment: Is `IsDigit` a property @jdweng?

Comment: The second option could effectively mutate the struct which is not a good idea. Also when you call a method on a struct a managed pointer is created and the struct value is boxed so it can pass the value to the method. Where as the static example does not require a pointer reference.

Comment: @jdweng I'm pretty sure that instance properties don't take up any additional memory, unless they have a backing store.

Comment: Yeah, I think there's something a bit fishy, or at least misleading about @jdweng 's comment. I'm not sure quite how virtual method tables work in C# or if they are even relevent to an implicitly sealed struct, but calling a method a "property"... hmm...

Comment: Not that `char` is a class anyway, but adding methods *or* properties doesn't add to the per-instance memory usage.

Comment: @Nico: How could the second option mutate a struct? And no, structs aren't boxed every time you call methods on them. (There are cases where that does happen, but not by default.)

Comment: @JonSkeet `public bool IsDigit() { this = '.'; return false; }` ? (ignoring readonly fields that is)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: But obviously you *wouldn't* do that. I expressed myself badly in the comment before. To put it another way: there are lots of instance methods on various value types (especially `DateTime`). Those *could* all be written to mutate the value as well, but we trust that they don't. What's special about `char.IsDigit` that makes it more sensitive to this theoretical possibility?

Comment: Nothing. Nothing at all.

Comment: It looks to me like the difference is somewhat arbitrary, but the type of operations we perform with `DateTime` make instance methods more convenient. We can write `var newDate = oldDate.AddDays(1);` instead of `var newDate = DateTime.AddDays(oldDate, 1);` Or `someDate.DayOfWeek` vs. `DateTime.DayOfWeek(someDate);` It looks a lot to me like a style preference, but if so I wonder if there were some very specific considerations and if the exact same choices would be made today. I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

We generally use static methods for defining utility functions(they are the functions for which an instance is not required). If the function is not a utility function, we make it an instance method